# Swift Compatibility Issue with XCFramework in Xcode for React Native App

Tags: swift, xcode, react-native, xcframework

I'm currently experiencing an issue with Swift compatibility in my Xcode project, which is part of a React Native application. The error message I'm receiving is:

```
Undefined symbol: __swift_FORCE_LOAD_$_swiftCompatibility56
```

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thank you in advance!

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Updated Xcode to the latest version.
- Recompiled the XCFramework library with a compatible Swift version.
- Updated the Swift version of my project.
- Cleaned the Build Folder in Xcode.
- Deleted the Derived Data for my project.
- Checked all project dependencies for compatibility issues.
- Reinstalled Xcode.

Unfortunately, none of these steps have resolved the issue. I'm still receiving the same error message when I try to build my project.

Here are the details of my setup:

- Xcode version: 14.2
- Swift version: 5
- React version: 18.2.0
- React Native version: 0.71.0

Comment: Are you sure you're on Xcode 14.2? Errors like this are common with RN on 14.3, but usually reverting to 14.2 resolves them.

Comment: @Abe yeah, I'm on 14.2. I haven't reinstalled Xcode, otherwise, tried everything that I could possibly think of.